# Is this mold in the crawlspace? Flip or flop?

Tags: water, subfloor, mold, crawlspace, damage

We are looking at putting an offer in on this house but are hesitant because it was recently flipped.  New everything cosmetic, looks like quality work. They also installed a new roof, HVAC +duct work, vapor barrier, and even a sump pump. This makes me wonder if there was a lot of moisture in the crawlspace previously and mold.  This is the main concern.  The house smells extremely strong of new paint, so it’s hard to detect anything that way. But I did crawl under the house and snapped these images of subfloor beams and foundation blocks in the crawlspace. It's dry down there right now but I'm assuming there may be some residual water damage still. Like maybe they fixed the root cause with the gutters outside and the sump pump but I'm worried about residual mold.  Are the black dots insect droppings or something else? Also I noticed some white stuff that looks like mold, possibly where the master bathroom is above (we noticed a soft spot in the bathroom floor in front of shower) What do you think? I'm also including a picture of orange dots I saw in the coat closet upstairs which seemed strange since it's all freshly painted.. Any input will be so helpful as were first-time home buyers! Thanks!  [image] [image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: The top pictures with the large areas look more like stains.  The bottom pictures with the small spots are possible mold or just stains also.  Can only tell if it is mold by having it tested and when tested they will you the type also, if dangerous or just icky looking.  If it not though out the house and just in a few spots, and the build quality of the house is very good, then it should not be the only reason of not buying, but might let you knock some of the price down.

Comment: Thank you for your input! yes I think I would definitely want to get those things tested and addressed before we closed on it.  The structure seemed around elsewhere , just those areas looked concerning.

Comment: Structure, electrical and plumbing are usually the most important.  If they are all good, a little mold is usually very easy to take care of, unless it is one of the very few types out of thousands that are very bad.  Testing is the only way to to tell.

Comment: The black spots look like mold.  This is not necessarily a deal killer, as in exposed places like this (floor joists in a crawl space) the mold is relatively easy (and cheap, compared to the cost of the house) to treat.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others they look like water stains. But the flippers may have fixed the problem. You should get it tested for moisture content. Buying a house is a big investment. I always hire an expert to check it out professionally.  They know the places likely to leak etc.

If you are borrowing money, it can be assurance for the bank.

If you want to do a preliminary test yourself, you can buy moisture testers online. Allowable moisture content should be in your local building code, it is here in NZ.

Answer (score 1):

The black spots look like mold.  This is not necessarily a deal killer, as in exposed places like this (floor joists in a crawl space) the mold is relatively easy (and cheap, compared to the cost of the house) to treat.

And no, just wiping it down with a bleach solution will not kill the mold.  The mold actually sends little tentacles/dendrites(?) into the wood.  These are not affected by the bleach, and so the mold can grow right back again.

But, I would have them (the sellers) remove all of the fiberglass insulation in the crawl space.  That's a disaster in the making, because if it ever gets wet (which it could, all it takes is a high dew point), it will never completely dry out.